# Angular Material's mat-autocomplete input is not getting disabled as expected

Tags: angular-material

I'm trying to disable an Angular Material Autocomplete component. I would have expected to just be able to set `disabled` on the input, but that does nothing. (I also tried setting `disabled` on mat-form-field and mat-autocomplete.) Setting `matAutocompleteDisabled` on input prevented the options from showing, but still allowed typing in the field. Setting `readonly` on input prevented typing, but it doesn't change the UI, so seems like that will be confusing for the user. Is this a bug, or am I missing something?

Here's the closest I've come so far, using `readonly` (and disabled isn't working as expected)

```
<form class="example-form">
  <mat-form-field class="example-full-width">
    <input type="text"
           disabled readonly
           placeholder="Pick one"
           aria-label="Number"
           matInput
           [formControl]="myControl"
           [matAutocomplete]="auto">
    <mat-autocomplete #auto="matAutocomplete">
      <mat-option *ngFor="let option of options" [value]="option">
        {{option}}
      </mat-option>
    </mat-autocomplete>
  </mat-form-field>
</form>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use formControl to set it, something like:

```
this.formGroupName.controls['myControl'].disable()
```

Comment: I'm using template driven forms. There should be a way to disable within the html instead of in code, right?

Comment: @SherriM if you are using template driven froms then how come this answer solve your problem?

Comment: I ended up updating my form to be reactive instead, and this works.

Answer (score 1):

Use [attr.disabled]="true". It will set the disabled to true.

Answer (score 0):

You can do css trick for this purpose.

Apply some class to parent tag of input. In you case upper tag is  `<mat-form-field class="example-full-width">` so i add **disable-block** class in this. And applied below css.

```
.disable-block {
    pointer-events: none;
    opacity: .7;
}
```

Full code here.

HTML

```
<form class="example-form">
  <mat-form-field class="example-full-width disable-block">
    <input type="text" disabled readonly placeholder="Pick one" aria-label="Number" matInput [formControl]="myControl" [matAutocomplete]="auto">
    <mat-autocomplete #auto="matAutocomplete">
      <mat-option *ngFor="let option of options" [value]="option">
        {{option}}
      </mat-option>
    </mat-autocomplete>
  </mat-form-field>
</form>
```

CSS

```
.disable-block {
  pointer-events: none;
  opacity: .7;
}
```

If you want more lighter text field then you can decrease opacity to .6 or .5 or more want you want.

Hope this will solve you problem.